# Get if an element can be clicked or not

Tags: windows, ui-automation

I am building a WPF application witch'll replace the windows cursor. What i need  to know is **if an item witch is under my cursor can be clicked** (I don't want to click it right now).

That element (a button, a link etc...) can be anywhere on windows (a desktop icon, an other WPF application, a website...). I make some search and it seem that i can find what i search in the assembly UIAutomation ... but i have no idea of how using it.

My idea is to get the position of the cursor and then :

-watch if their is an item under
-watch if that item can be clicked

Someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this when your cursor is over any control in any application, or only over your own app itself? Can you describe more about how your app will be used?

Comment: I want to do this when my cursor is hover any application. In fact i need it to work in one WPF application, but i have no access to that application. My app will be used with a kinect, i already have the methode witch'll throw the click, what i need is a condition witch say  when to throw it. As i can't add any event to the buttons (as onMouseHover), i need to add to the cursor an ability to see if he is hover something that can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in general to tell if an item can be clicked or not. But you might be able to make a good enough guess for your application.

The problem is has to do with how clicks work in the first place: Windows always sends a click, and it's up to the application to decide whether or how to respond to it. Usually the background of form won't respond - but some do. Usually buttons will respond; but there may be some that don't. And some types of controls may respond differently depending on where you click: if you click a link in a text control, it will activate the link; click the text, and it will move the insertion point.

So the best bet is to always allow a click to be sent - that's how a mouse works anyhow.

But if you want to display a hint, you could try using UIAutomation to get the AutomationElement.FromPoint, get its ControlType and IsEnabled properties, and if it is something like Button, ListItem, TabItem, and so on, and it is enabled, then it's *probably* clickable.

If you only need to work against one or two specific apps, you may be able to come up with a complete list of the types that are clickable or not for those applications, but if you want to work with any application, you'll need to be aware that you won't always be accurate, so should allow the user to override and send a click anyway, even if you aren't displaying the right indicator.